# Can we have tag icons?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Some tags on StackOverflow have icons, such as

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and so on.

> **Question**: Can we have tag icons here at maths.SE?

I mean "can" in the sense of "are we capable of having".  I'm not saying we should or should not have this.

Comment: Note that on SO these icons are actually indications of [sponserships/branding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187/214632).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that.  I guess we won't be having a  little Petersen graph next to [tag:graph-theory] then.

Comment: I wouldn't see why we couldn't do that. Can't we have non-branding tag photos?

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones: Probably not. I've done a quick check in a few other SE sites, and haven't been able to find icons on any tags (including on arqade.SE which has many tags that would be well-suited for actual branding).  Perhaps in the future it would be possible, but I don't think SE would want to do something that might devalue part of their advertising initiative on SO.  In the meantime, you _could_ modify the code of [this user script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24480/214632) to make it display icons of your choosing.  (I haven't tried it out, so I have no idea if it works at all.)

Comment: I think this would be a horrible idea! Think of the arguments and opinions, and also wonder how we night represent, say, the ring theory tag? Or the group theory tag? Real analysis? Number theory?

Comment: I only intend the above question at the technical level.  I'm also unsure if it would be a good idea.  It sounds like it won't be possible regardless, so it's somewhat moot whether or not it's a good idea to implement.

Comment: @user1729 Not every tag needs to be icon'd.  I do think it would be incredibly helpful though, for distinguishing tags with new users.  For example, a precalculus student may use the [tag:graph-theory] tag for a question involving the graph of a function.  An icon that looks nothing like the graph of a function may cause them to think about this for a second or two longer--enough to encourage them to read the tag wiki.

Comment: On another note: I *really* like this idea, and would love to see it turned into a feature request... :)

Comment: @anorton That is a good point. However, I suspect the most common mix-ups would be abstract algebra and graph theory...but abstract algebra doesn't really have a picture...

Comment: "[tag:homework] is brought to you by wolfram alpha" hm...

Answer (score 17):

Here's what it looks like if we modify Stephen A. Goss's script StackOverflow script ([link](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/59074)) to work on maths.SE:

I made these icons myself:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

These I "borrowed" off the internet:

[image]

[image]

---

These are icons for software:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice ones (though combinatorics is a bit too small for me to identify) - I wonder what the SE team's stance on icons for non-free software is...

Comment: I really like some of these and I think that in addition to looking nice they could help a little for new users not to miss-tag (but mainly I like the way they look)

Comment: We definitely need to remove the brackets

Comment: Hmm... The link no longer works...